# How to generate an array of a specific value with given input array in C code

Tags: arrays, c, indexing, element

The title may be a little confusing so I will explain my goal a bit more in detail here;
I want to write a code that takes an input array of the x numbers

```
index_x = [0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0];
```

Then I want to write a logic that will generate an array that has the index of all the 1s

```
index_ones = [3,5,9,12];
```

Current code slightly modified from Jacon:

Edit 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int index_x[] = {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0};      // any number of elements
int len = 12;

int main(void) {

    int arr[len];
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if (index_x[i])
            arr[j++] = i;                     // save and advance j only if value is "1"

    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)               // only print below j !
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
2
4
8
11
```

From this output, I would like to generate another array that is the difference between these elements. In this case the new array would be {2,4,3}.

Edit 2: I will move this to another thread as the discussion has now moved from one problem to another. Do not want to complicate things for future users.

Comment: Do you know how to write a loop? Do you know how to iterate over the array? Could you write code that copies the 1s into another array (`[1,1,1,1]`)? How do you perform this operation with paper and pencil?

Comment: Start with a similar but simpler problem. Can you loop over and print each element in `index_x`? Can you loop over and print them with an index?

Comment: 'arr[j++] = i + 1;' ?

Comment: @tstanisl Yup that works but I realize I don't have to do this for the overall scope so I have scratched that out

Comment: @tstanisl yes. Or correct it later: `printf("%d\n", ++arr[i]);` (two spaces less, but hidden in the printf()).  But I see the Q has changed again!

Comment: @tstanisl haha yes! I'm not sure whether to create a new thread or keep to this one

Comment: Difference now? For heavens sake, it is the same thing! _Guidance_, truly!  `int diffarr[len];` and a for loop. `-` is minus, and indexes can be expressions `[i+1]`. Just don't forget that the last element has no difference so mind the edge.

Comment: But wait: difference you can also get directly by counting the distance (in elements) between the "1"s (with one for loop). Did you say something about overall scope?

Comment: @Jacon Ah you're right! Let me try implementing that thank you!  Also wouldn't int diffarr[len] not work as the length is not 128. Yup, this is just a small portion of my entire project where I got stuck haha.

Comment: @CodingCurry Note `int len = 12; ... for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)` is incorrect as the array count is 13.

Comment: @CodingCurry Rather than a goal of "generate an array", consider allocating memory, more portable,  easier to handle and perform error checking.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not know how many indexes you need you will need to allocate the memory dynamically. You need also to remember the number of indexes

```
struct index
{
    size_t size;
    size_t indexes[];
};


struct index *addIndex(struct index *index, size_t pos)
{
    size_t new_size = index ? index -> size + 1 : 1;

    index = realloc(index, sizeof(*index) + new_size * sizeof(index -> indexes[0]));
    if(index)
    {
        index -> size = new_size;
        index -> indexes[new_size - 1] = pos;
    }
    return index;
}

struct index *buildIndex(int *arr, size_t arr_size, int val)
{
    struct index *index = NULL, *tmp; 

    for(size_t pos = 0; pos < arr_size; pos++)
    {
        if(arr[pos] == val) 
        {
            tmp = addIndex(index, pos);
            if(tmp) index = tmp;
            else { /* error handling */ }
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: If I assume the input array to always be a 128 boolean array, I won't have to allocate the memory dynamically correct?

Comment: @CodingCurry I do not understand the problem You will allocate as much memory as needed (in border case when all elements are zero you will no allocate any  memory)

Answer (score 0):

Find array element count of `index_x[]`.

```
int index_x[] = {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0}; 
...
// e.g. 13, not 12 as implied with int len = 12;
size_t index_x_count = sizeof index_x / sizeof index_x[0];
```

Then run through `index_x[]` to find numbers of the *ones*.

```
size_t ones = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < index_x_count; i++) {
   if (index_x[i] == 1) {
     ones++; 
  }
}
```

Now we know the size needed for "generate an array that has the index of all the 1s"

```
// Error check, can't have array size 0
if (ones == 0) Handle_patholocial_case();
// We should avoid forming huge arrays.  10000 is arbitrary.
// When large, rather than form _arrays_, allocate memory (not shown).
if (ones > 10000) Handle_patholocial_case();
// Form the array
int arr[ones];

size_t a = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < ones; i++) {
   if (index_x[i] == 1) {
    arr[a++] = i; 
  }
}
```

> generate another array that is the difference between these elements.

```
// Error check for at least one difference, can't have array size 0
if (ones <= 1) Handle_patholocial_case();
// Form the array
size_t diff_count = ones - 1;
int diff[diff_count];

for (size_t d = 0; d < diff_count; d++) {
  diff[a] = arr[d+1] - arr[d]; 
}
```

Do something with `diff[]`

```
for (size_t d = 0; d < diff_count; d++) {
  printf("%d ", diff[d]);
}
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding this. I'm using the variables from the code I posted but apply the logic you mentioned. What is the reason behind this: size_t diff_count = ones - 1?

Comment: @CodingCurry, in an array of 4 `int` like { 2, 4, 8, 11}, how many differences are there?

Comment: There are 2 differences

Comment: @CodingCurry  Hmm, 4-2, 8-4, 11-8 looks like 3 differences.